# .htaccess not working (mod_rewrite)

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

**Edit:** I am pretty sure my .htaccess file is NOT being executed, and the problem is NOT with my rewrite rules.

I have not having any luck getting my .htaccess with mod_rewrite working.  Basically all I am trying to do is remove 'www' from "http://www.site.com" and "https://www.site.com".

If there is anything I am missing (conf files, etc let me know I willl update this)

I jsut can't see whats wrong here... I am using a 1&1 VPS III Virtual private server... anyone ever have this issue?

I am using Ubuntu 8.04 Server LTS.

Here is my .htaccess file (located @ /var/www/site/trunk/html/)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) //%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My mod_rewrite is enabled:

The auto regenerated sym link is there in mods-available and /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ contains mod_rewrite.so

```
root@s15348441:/etc/apache2/mods-available# more rewrite.load
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so


root@s15348441:/var/log# apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

My apache config files:

apache2.conf

```
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "/var/log/apache2/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "" will be interpreted by the
# server as "//var/log/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.1/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#<IfModule !mpm_winnt.c>
#<IfModule !mpm_netware.c>
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock
#</IfModule>
#</IfModule>

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

#
# ServerTokens
# This directive configures what you return as the Server HTTP response
# Header. The default is 'Full' which sends information about the OS-Type
# and compiled in modules.
# Set to one of:  Full | OS | Minor | Minimal | Major | Prod
# where Full conveys the most information, and Prod the least.
#
ServerTokens Full

#
# Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
# name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP directory 
# listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI generated 
# documents or custom error documents).
# Set to "EMail" to also include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
# Set to one of:  On | Off | EMail
#
ServerSignature On


#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# Putting this all together, we can internationalize error responses.
#
# We use Alias to redirect any /error/HTTP_<error>.html.var response to
# our collection of by-error message multi-language collections.  We use 
# includes to substitute the appropriate text.
#
# You can modify the messages' appearance without changing any of the
# default HTTP_<error>.html.var files by adding the line:
#
#   Alias /error/include/ "/your/include/path/"
#
# which allows you to create your own set of files by starting with the
# /usr/share/apache2/error/include/ files and copying them to /your/include/path/, 
# even on a per-VirtualHost basis.  The default include files will display
# your Apache version number and your ServerAdmin email address regardless
# of the setting of ServerSignature.
#
# The internationalized error documents require mod_alias, mod_include
# and mod_negotiation.  To activate them, uncomment the following 30 lines.

#    Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
#
#    <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/error">
#        AllowOverride None
#        Options IncludesNoExec
#        AddOutputFilter Includes html
#        AddHandler type-map var
#        Order allow,deny
#        Allow from all
#        LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it nl sv pt-br ro
#        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
#    </Directory>
#
#    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var



# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

My default config file for www on apache

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@site.com

    #SSLEnable
    #SSLVerifyClient none
    #SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt  
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key  

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/trunk/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site/trunk/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My ssl config file

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@site.com

    #SSLEnable
    #SSLVerifyClient none
    #SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt  
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key  

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/trunk/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site/trunk/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key


    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is blank

The directory /etc/apache2/conf.d has nothing in it but one file (charset)

contents of /etc/apache2/conf.dcharset

```
# Read the documentation before enabling AddDefaultCharset.
# In general, it is only a good idea if you know that all your files
# have this encoding. It will override any encoding given in the files
# in meta http-equiv or xml encoding tags.

#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

My apache error.log

```
[Wed Jun 03 00:12:31 2009] [error] [client 216.168.43.234] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Wed Jun 03 05:03:51 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:03:54 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:13:48 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:13:51 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:13:54 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:13:57 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:17:28 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 05:26:23 2009] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jun 03 05:26:34 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 06:03:41 2009] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jun 03 06:03:51 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 06:25:07 2009] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jun 03 06:25:17 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 12:09:25 2009] [error] [client 61.139.105.163] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/fastenv
[Wed Jun 03 15:04:42 2009] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Jun 03 15:04:43 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 15:29:51 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 15:29:54 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 15:30:32 2009] [error] [client 99.247.237.46] File does not exist: /var/www/site/trunk/html/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 03 15:45:54 2009] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jun 03 15:46:05 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: You should add relevant log entries if you have them :-)

Comment: added the apache error log file, are there any others I should post?

Comment: Can apache user read the .htaccess file?

Comment: The .htaccess file looks like this -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 121 Jun  3 19:48 .htaccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the rewrite rules directly into the VirtualHost config section (not under a "Directory" rule)

This way you can bypass any problems that may be cause by .htaccess and path identification mechanisms.

Check if rewrite_module is loaded into apache:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

If not enabled, enable the mod_rewrite with

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

This will set up necessary links under mods-**enabled** (not mods-*available*)

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled, check the setup & logs.  I'll try your VHost config thing though.

Comment: I put it in the virtual host section, and it did not work. No errors of course.

Comment: try with a simpler redirect without condition. Also, I suspect module is not enabled, try "apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES" and look for rewrite_module. The links should be under "mods-enabled" to fix this run "a2enmod rewrite"

Comment: It's loaded, I pout the output above.  Its not executing the .htaccess I think... still no idea why this is not working.

Comment: try a most simple rewrite in a vhost configuration, NOT .htaccess. Then you can isolate the problem in .htaccess execution or the rewrite itself.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. Good troubleshooting steps is try puting garbage in your various config files to see which ones are *actually* being read during the reload.

Answer (score 0):

> root@s15348441:/etc/apache2/mods-available# more rewrite.load
>   LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

Check for it in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` to see if it's actually getting pulled into the Apache configuration. I suspect that the rewrite module simply isn't being loaded (though I'd have expected to see an error in the logs about it).

Comment: The auto regenerated sym-link is there in mods-available and /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ contains mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Right, but your configuration includes *.conf and *.load from mods-enabled, *not* mods-available. You can run httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES to list all modules being loaded.

Comment: ok cool, I will check now

Comment: I am running apache2, I don't have httpd -bash: httpd: command not found

Comment: If my configuration includeded *.conf and *.load from mods-available, my apache server would load them all.

Answer (score 0):

Debian-based distros like Ubuntu call it apache instead of httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your group and user permissions?

If you use:

```
ls -lah <path to file>
```

it will give you output like:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 <group> <user> 7.5K Jun  7 22:49 <path to file>
```

If they are incorrect, simply use

`chown <user>:<group> <path to file>`