# simple mod_rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect users from http://uppereast.com to http://nyclocalliving.com. This is the .htaccess file I have below, but I am not getting redirected to my new URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uppereast.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nyclocalliving.com [L,R=301]
...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are both uppereast.com and nyclocalliving.com serving content out of the same directory?

Comment: Yes, both uppereast.com and nyclocalliving.com are being served from the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try [R=301,L] instead of [L,R=301].

Note that the way you have it written, uppereast.com would match, but not www.uppereast.com.

Comment: Hmm, no dice. I understand that I'm only matching on http://uppereast.com. That's just the beginning test case. But I can't get that going. Basically, this is a subset of this issue: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/68838/broken-htaccess-modrewrite

I figured I should tackle that in smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the escape of your regexp '.' character in the host name pattern for RewriteCond:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uppereast\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nyclocalliving.com [L,R=301]
...
```

^uppereast**\**.com$

Also, the use of $ is not needed on the rule, all you need is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nyclocalliving.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uppereast\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nyclocalliving.com [L,R=301]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uppereast*\*.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nyclocalliving.com [L,R=301]


I tried both of these, but no dice. Could the apache segmentation faults have anything to do with this?
http://serverfault.com/questions/68838/broken-htaccess-modrewrite

Comment: The segfault might (that ** in my comment above is this website screwing up, it was supposed to bold the \ character as an example to you only) be the source. The code snippet I gave above should work 100%, I use rewrite rules similar to this all the time to trap and redirect non-www URLS to their www. domain counterpart; many times they're more complex. Without escaping the '.' before com you're using a regexp pattern by mistake when you meant to match a single '.' character. Try turning on RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to capture the rewrite and discover the cause of your segfaults.